# Builtin method or property so that we can fix the form size by disabling the drag menu at both right and buttom side of form

Tags: c#, winforms

We are working on windows based .Net application where we are designing forms like we used to do in .Net IDE, designing Winforms using the `IServiceProvider` interface and `BasicHostLoader` abstract class.

We are facing a problem with adding new forms in to designer. We want to fix the size of form a but as by default at design time form are resizable we can’t able to fix the form.

We have added a method to stop resizing in the `Resize` method, we are again storing the original size so it seem form size doesn’t changes while dragging the form but we want to disable the drag mouse menu cursor while taking the mouse to right and button border center of form.

Could you suggest any inbuilt method or property so that we can fix the form size by disabling the drag menu at both right and button side of form.

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/KkQFqP
Screen shot

Answer (score 0):

When you're designing the form, set the `FormBorderStyle` to `Sizable`.  When you have the size you want, set the `FormBorderStyle` to a fixed style.